# get list of non return / not found inputs sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with a SQL query. I can't figure it out. Please help.

If I input `WHERE NMR IN (1,3,5,7,9)`

5 actually does not exists in the table

I get this result

```
NMR
1
3
7
9


SELECT NMR FROM NMRLIST
WHERE NMR IN (1,3,5,7,9)
```

But I need a result like:

```
NMR    Found
1       Yes
3       Yes
5       No
7       Yes
9       Yes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `VALUES` and then `LEFT JOIN` to your table:

```
SELECT V.NMR,
       CASE WHEN NL.NMR IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS Found
FROM (VALUES(1),(3),(5),(7),(9))V(NMR)
     LEFT JOIN dbo.NMRLIST NL ON V.NMR = NL.NMR;
```

*Note, I assume that `NMR` is a unique value in the table `dbo.NMRLIST`. If not, you'll need to use some aggregation.*

Comment: My apologies, i would not know the inputs , 1,3,5,7,9 were just as example. but I need to know from inputs which numbers were found in the table and which numbers were not found (may be not exists in the table)

Comment: In that case, you can assign the input to a table variable or temp table and pass it in above query instead of values.

Comment: Then, as Cylar notes, use a table-type parameter instead, @Arman and then `LEFT JOIN` to your table. `VALUES` is simply a table construct at the end of the day, so can easily be replaced with a table variable/parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can try below -

```
select a.num, case when b.nmr is null then 'No' else 'Yes' end as found
from
(
   select 1 as num union all select 3 union all select 5 union all select 7 union all select 9
)A left join NMRLIST b on a.num=b.NMR and NMR IN (1,3,5,7,9)
```

Comment: My apologies, i would not know the inputs , 1,3,5,7,9 were just as example. but I need to know from inputs which numbers were found in the table and which numbers were not found (may be not exists in the table)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following query-

```
SELECT V.NMR,
       CASE WHEN NL.NMR IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS Found
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT NMR FROM NMRLIST)V(NMR)
     LEFT JOIN dbo.NMRLIST NL ON V.NMR = NL.NMR;
```

Please comment if you have any doubt?

Comment: it returns only yes

Comment: Why would this return a row for `NMR` having a value of `5`, when the OP specifically states that `5` does not exist in the table `NMRLIST`?

Comment: e.g. if you have request to buy 100s of items and when you input the list it will only return the items exists in your product table then you need to reply client that you can sell 1,3,7 and 9 but you cant sell 5 because you do not stock 5. how you will find all not exists / not found items in sql.